# Java does not play multi channel wave file

Tags: java, audio, surround

I am unable to play a multi channel wave file in java using javax.sound.sampled package.
I am using an external USB 7.1 surround sound card from logilink.
The wave file is generated by myself. If I generate a stereo track, I am able to play the file. If I use the 6 channel track, I get the following error message:

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED     48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, 6 channels, 12 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
```

I checked if the line is supported and it is by using this code

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(48000, 16, 6, true, false);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
if (info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
  // is supported
}
```

I play the wave file as follows:

```
AudioListener listener = new AudioListener();
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(clipFile);
Clip clip = null;
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.addLineListener(listener);
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.start();
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I guess that's the key part of the error message: "little-endian not supported". Not an expert in wav files, but the place where you generate the file - is there a setting for big-endian there?

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, thanks for replying.
I am just creating a wave file with some simple tones. I am setting the wave file header by my own, so maybe I can change the endian. I must admit I was also thinking, it could be the endian thing but did not look into it if I am really able to change it...

Comment: The strange thing is, if I change in the header wave file from multi channel to stereo, I am able to play the wave file.